# How can I get Phone wallpaper in Android?

Tags: android

I am working on an Android application. How can I get Phone wallpaper in Android? Please help me. Give me the sample code example.

Comment: You may get a better response rate if you begin to mark helpful and correct answers as accepted by selecting the check-mark found on the left of the appropriate answer.

Comment: Whoever told you that Stack Overflow is a "give me teh codez!" website was sadly mistaken. This is not how you ask a question.

Comment: For the record, he does come back to thank people who answered his questions, he just does not tick the checkbox. He probably does not realize there is a checkbox in the first place.

Answer (score 11):

You need to use [`WallpaperManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html) which, among other things mentioned in the documentation, allows you to get the current wallpaper.

The following snippet will get the current wallpaper (or the system default if no wallpaper is set).

```
final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
```

Answer (score 0):

From your activity call

this.getWallpaper();

Answer (score -1):

Wallpaper can be get using getDrawable() of Wallpaper class [How can I get Phone wallpaper in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013085/how-to-get-phone-wallpaper-in-android)