# How to make a Phonegap app's background transparent?

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

How can Phonegap users make their app's backgrounds transparent, to reveal a device's homescreen?

My html form has a background image.  Both measure 460h x 320w.

When I test the html on my tablet (1024h x 600w), the app displays properly, but the background color surrounding the form is either black or white depending on which setting I used in my localStorage.java file.

I only want the background color transparent.  The form and image should remain the same.

I am using Eclipse as my IDE to convert my html & css to an Android app.

I have referenced these two Stack Overflow posts, but again, no fruit:

[How to make the PhoneGap app's background transparent and revealing the current system wallpaper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874415/how-to-make-the-phonegap-apps-background-transparent-and-revealing-the-current)

[How do I set a background image on the WebView on Cordova/PhoneGap for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068541/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-on-the-webview-on-cordova-phonegap-for-android?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

I have also tried android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent..", to no avail.

Here is the code I use with some of the commented-out things I have tried:

html body style:

```
<body style="margin:0px;font-family:Helvetica;background-image:url ('droid.png');     
background-Repeat:no-repeat;background-color:transparent !important;">
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="460dp"
 >
</LinearLayout>
```

localStorage.java:

```
package com.ABC.localStorage;

/* import android.app.Activity; */
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;
import android.graphics.Color;

public class localStorage extends DroidGap
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        super.setIntegerProperty("backgroundColor", Color.TRANSPARENT);
        /* super.appView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); */        
       /* appView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); */
       /* appView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255,37,37)); */
       /* appView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000); */
      /* appView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(125,255,37,37)); */
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
      package="com.ABC.localStorage" android:versionName="1.1" android:versionCode="5" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon"        
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/TransparentFloatingApp"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name="localStorage"   
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
                 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
</manifest>
```

style.xml:

```
<resources>

  <style name="Theme" parent="android:Theme" />

  <style name="TransparentFloatingApp">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
      <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
  </style>

  <drawable name="transparent_background">#00000000</drawable>

</resources>
```

Comment: I've never tried this but it strikes me as something which is probably not possible. Apps don't work like windows. They are not "on top" of the phone's home screen. Your best bet would probably be to get the current wallpaper like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013085/how-can-i-get-phone-wallpaper-in-android and set that as the background. Not sure that's possible with PhoneGap, however.

Comment: I am sure that it is possible.  What I want to do can be done using the standard Android webview, I have done it, but I just don't know how to do it with Phonegap generated code.  I'm sure it is something simple.  The standard Android webview wouldn't play nice with my code for some reason, so I used Phonegap instead.  It uses appview, but I'm a newbie to Android programming and I don't have enough experience to make the correct adjustments.  @Simon MacDonald, what do you know about this?

Comment: @zhouqicf , do you possibly know of some code that I could use to get my project to work?  Last year you had a similar question on Stack Overflow.  The link is above in my question.

Comment: Any developments on this Krang?